# Ajax post has empty values on the server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, base64

I'm trying to save an image file out of a base64 string received from the client side.

So I have this ajax post:

```
 $.ajax({type: "POST", url: "upload_post.php", data: postData, dataType: "text", success: function(result){
        alert("post result: " + result + " - data:" + postData);
        location.reload();
    }});
```

Here is an example of `postData` (which I know contains data):

```
{"ship_id":"407","base64_upload":"ABCSFSAFGDGFA....."}
```

Now here is a my php code that handles this post:

```
$id = $_POST['ship_id'];
$img = $_POST['base64_upload'];
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'news.site.com/docs/'.$id.'/');
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file. '.$file.'';
```

The problem is  the $_POST variables are always empty. why is that? json related? location.reload() related? and how do I fix it?

**EDIT**

I have got these variables posted with actual data by doing `JSON.parse(postData)` on the ajax data. Now my problem is I still can't save the image file. any help?

Comment: Why you use `location.reload() ` since you use `ajax request` try to remove this function and tell us what do you get.

Comment: as location.reload is done "on success", it has no bearing on your problem. what do you get for `result` in the alert?

Comment: when i remove location.reload() it doesn't seem to post at all. only when I refresh the page.

Comment: for result I get `post result: id:  img: Unable to save the file. news.site.com/docs//58c9f....png - data: (original postData)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, I'm answering my own question.
The problem was I have `define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'news.site.com/docs/'.$id.'/');`
and then `$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';` and this `UPLOAD_DIR` directory doesn't really exists. So I added a check if it exists and then created the directory before creating the file:

```
$id = $_POST['ship_id'];
$img = $_POST['base64_upload'];
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'news.site.com/docs/'.$id.'/');
$file2 = UPLOAD_DIR;
if(!file_exists($file2)){
    mkdir($file2, 0777, true);
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file. '.$file.'';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do for jQuery Post. I hope it helps you

```
$.post("upload_post.php",
{
    ship_id: "407",
    base64_upload: "ABCSFSAFGDGFA....."
},
function(data, status){
    alert("post result: " + status+ " - data:" + data);
    location.reload();
});
```

You fetch the data in php exactly the same.

Comment: Not working either, not getting the print from the server and this post is not stable. one time it works and one time it doesn't. @adan